# How to use pandas to parse a text file and create a list

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I am trying to use pandas to create a list/array containing all the words from the "review/text" field of the following text file :

```
product/productId: B001E4KFG0 review/userId: A3SGXH7AUHU8GW review/profileName: delmartian review/helpfulness: 1/1 review/score:
5.0 review/time: 1303862400 review/summary: Good Quality Dog Food review/text: I have bought several of the Vitality canned dog food products and have found them all to be of good quality. The product looks more like a stew than a processed meat and it smells better. My Labrador is finicky and she appreciates this product better than  most.

product/productId: B00813GRG4 review/userId: A1D87F6ZCVE5NK review/profileName: dll pa review/helpfulness: 0/0 review/score: 1.0 review/time: 1346976000 review/summary: Not as Advertised review/text: Product arrived labeled as Jumbo Salted Peanuts...
```

(text file foods.txt available at : http://snap.stanford.edu/data/web-FineFoods.html)

My ultimate goal is to identify all the unique words that appear in the review/text field.

I have written the following code :

```
    import pandas as pd
    
    f=open("foods.txt","r")
    df=pd.read_csv(f,names=['product/productId','review/userId','review/profileName','review/helpfulness','review/score','review/time','review/summary'])
    selected = df[ df['review/summary'] ] 
    print(selected)

selected.to_csv('result.csv', sep=' ', header=False)
```

However, I am getting the error below :

```
ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values
```

Any suggestions / comment ?

Comment: for the sample data you provided, can you elaborate what desired output looks like?

Comment: Hi, I posted a separate answer. Please check.

Comment: are the first two lines in your source text file part of a single line or is it two separate lines? The line starting with `product/productId: B001E4KFG0` and `5.0 review/time: 1303862400`

Comment: i cant really tell, when i open the text file from the Stanford webpage, everything seems to be on the same line but when I open the same file in VSCode they appear separately. Sorry !

Comment: I posed the code to read through the file and extract the information you need. I assume that each record may be split into multiple lines and the start of each record is `product/productId:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will have to do this to extract all the records from the file and get the review/summary values. You don't need a dataframe.

```
#create a dictionary to store the list of review summary values
d = {'review summary':[]}

#function to extract only the review_summary from the line
def split_review_summary(full_line):
    
    #find review/text and exclude it from the line
    found = full_line.find('review/text:')
    if found >= 0:
        full_line = full_line[:found]

    #find review summary. All text to the right is review summary
    #add this to the dictionary
    found = full_line.find('review/summary:')
    if found >= 0:
        review_summary = full_line[(found + 15):]
        d['review summary'].append(review_summary)

#open the file for reading
with open ("xyz.txt","r") as f:
    #read the first line
    new_line = f.readline().rstrip('\n')
    #loop through the rest of the lines
    for line in f:
        #remove newline from the data
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        
        #if the line starts with product/productId, then its a new entry
        #process the previous line and strip out the review_summary
        #to do that, call split_review_summary function
        
        if line[:17] == 'product/productId':
            split_review_summary(new_line)
            #reset new_line to the current line
            new_line = line
        else:
            #append to the new_line as its part of the previous record
            new_line += line

#the last full record has not been processed
#So send it to split_review_summary to extract review summary
split_review_summary(new_line)

#now dictionary d has all the review summary items
print (d)
```

The output of this will be:

```
{'review summary': [' Good Quality Dog Food ', ' Not as Advertised ']}
```

I think your scope of the question also included writing to a new file.

You can open a file and write the dictionary as one line. That will contain all the details. I will leave it for you to solve that part.

Comment: If the above code solved your problem, feel free to read about what to do when someone [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) your question.

Answer (score 0):

A CSV file stands for **Comma**-Separated Values. I am not seeing any comas in your file.

It looks like a broken dictionary (missing separating commas for each entry):

```
my_dict ={
 'productid': 12312312,
 'some_key': 'I am the key!',
}
```

Comment: the file foods.txt has no comma, in that case how should i proceed ? i just want to select the words in each of the "review/text" header/row and put them in a list one by one

Comment: You could use RegEx to find the patterns you need. It shouldn't be too hard. Learn RegEx the fun way : https://regexr.com/

Comment: I am not quite able to use the RegEx, is there any other way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the link provided by S.Ghoshal and arrived at this :

```
#Opening your file
your_file = open('foods.txt')

#Reading every line
reviews = your_file.readlines()

reviews_array = []
dictionary = {}

#We are going through every line and skip it when we see that it's a blank line
for review in reviews:
    this_line = review.split(":")
    if len(this_line) > 1:
        #The blank lines are less than 1 in length after the split
        dictionary[this_line[0]] = this_line[1].strip()
        #Every first part before ":" is the key of the dictionary, and the second part id the content.
    else:
        #If a blank linee was found lets save the object in the array and reset it
        #for the next review
        reviews_array.append(dictionary)
        dictionary = {}

#Append the last object because it goes out the last else
reviews_array.append(dictionary)

f1=open("output.txt","a")
for r in reviews_array:
    print(r['review/text'], file=f1)
f1.close()
```

Now all the words in the lines beginning with review/text are dumped in a file. Next I need to create a list with all the unique words.